# Default and parametrised constructors

Tags: c++

Is this statement true that **declaring a constructor with arguments hides the default
constructor and you cannot invoke the default constructor**.

Answer (score 8):

Not exactly. Instead it suppresses the generation of compiler-provided default constructor. Consider:

```
class Class1 {
};
```

`Class1` will have a compiler-generated default constructor, so you can call `new Class1()`, while

```
class Class2 {
    Class2( int );
}
```

will not have a compiler-generated default constructor. So you can't call `new Class2()` unless you explicitly declare a default constructor for `Class2`:

```
class Class2 {
public:
    Class2();
    Class2( int );
}
```

Comment: Rather than specifying multiple constructors ,the best way is to use default argument like this :

class MyClass { 

int i; 
public: 

MyClass(int i = 0) { this->i = i}

};

Comment: @Mac: Sometimes what you suggest is better, sometimes not - depends on exact scenario.